# If statement in an if statement

Tags: powershell

For an assignment I have to prove that if statements can be placed within if statements in a Powershell script. Therefore I made the enclosed script. I am however not sure whether the script I have describes two separate if statements or would be considered an if within an if.

```
[int]$a = Read-host "Please input a number." 
if ($a –eq 5) { 
Write-Host “a is 5” } 
if ($a –ne 5) { 
Write-Host “a isn't 5” }
Read-host
```

Any help on this one?

---

Thank you for your answer. Why does this not work however?

```
if ($a –lt 2) { 
    if ($a –lt 3) {       
        if ($a –lt 4) { 
             if ($a –lt 5) {  
             Write-Host “a is less than 5” }
        Write-Host “a is less than 4” } 
    Write-Host “a is less than 3” }
Write-Host “a is less than 2” }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, these are two separate if statements. Nested would be:

```
if ($a –lt 5) { 
  if ($a –ne 2) { 
  Write-Host “a isn't 2” }
Write-Host “a is lt 5” }
```

Comment: Hmm. It works for me. If I do `[int]$a = Read-host "Please input a number."` and type 3 to the prompt and then exec the above stmts, my output is `a isn't 2\n a is lt 5`

Comment: Your edited post also works. But, however, because the outermost if checks for lt 2, all the other inner if's have only the chance to be evaluated, if a is lt 2, e.g. 1, but then the inner ifs are kind of trivial: If something is less than 2, then its also less than any number bigger than 2. So maybe you want to reverse the order of numbers you want to compare to: first use 5, then 4, then 3 and so on...